# Scrolltop() (can't reverse the animation)

Tags: javascript, web

Hey I'm trying to get the 2 divs move out of each other by moving them 10% left and 10% right. They will move out of each other after the 1000 but won't move back after I scroll back before 1000

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var jq  = $("#jqimg")
var kevin = $("#kevinimg")


 $(window).scroll(function () {

      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
        kevin.animate({
            marginLeft: "10%",
        },600);

        jq.animate({
            marginRight:"10%",
        },600);

      } 

  });
});
```

I tried to add this but that just breaks it

```
   else {
        kevin.animate({
            marginLeft: "0%",
        },600);

        jq.animate({
            marginRight:"0%",
        },600);

      }
```

anyone have a solution?

Comment: can you share a little of your html structure, specifically pertaining to how the image elements are placed and their css style attributes?

Answer (score 1):

It's because a previous animation is not completed. Use `queue: false` to prevent animation chaining. And use `marginLeft: null` instead of `0%` to remove margin property from style attribute. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/byzq104u/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
        $('div').animate({
            marginLeft: '10%'
        }, {
            queue: false
        });
    } else {
        $('div').animate({
            marginLeft: null
        }, {
            queue: false
        });
    }
});
```

Another way is to use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) or [`.finish()`](http://api.jquery.com/finish/). But in this case you loose another animation process on the element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/foxm21yu/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
        $('div').stop().animate({
            marginLeft: '10%'
        });
    } else {
        $('div').stop().animate({
            marginLeft: null
        });
    }
});
```